# How come you can create an interface instance in Office Interop?

Tags: ms-word

I've seen this quite a few times while using Office Interop classes

```
this.CustomXMLParts.Add(MyResources.Data, new Office.CustomXMLSchemaCollection());
```

If I hover over the CustomXMLSchemaCollection class, it shows up as an interface. Then how come I can do a new on it ? What gives?
BTW this code compiles and works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating an instance of the `CustomXMLSchemaCollection` interface but an instance of the `CustomXMLSchemaCollectionClass` coclass.

The definition for `CustomXMLSchemaCollection` interface is:

```
[Guid("000CDB02-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[CoClass(typeof(CustomXMLSchemaCollectionClass))]
public interface CustomXMLSchemaCollection : _CustomXMLSchemaCollection
{
}
```

This means that the designated coclass that implements the interface is `CustomXMLSchemaCollectionClass`. My guess is that when the C# compiler sees the new for `CustomXMLSchemaCollection` interface it translates it to create a COM instance of the `CustomXMLSchemaCollectionClass` based on the attributes provided with the interface.

After writing this simple example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    using System;
    using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Office.CustomXMLSchemaCollection test = new Office.CustomXMLSchemaCollection();
        }
    }
}
```

I just ran [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx) and get the following MSIL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class [Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core]Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomXMLSchemaCollection test)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void [Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core]Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomXMLSchemaCollectionClass::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

As you can see the class that is constructed is `CustomXMLSchemaCollectionClass` to prove my initial assumption.

Comment: OK COM Magic at work again. - Seems like the CoClass Attribute is the key to this off-the-trodden-path behavior. thx